# Css float next to HR-Line

Tags: css, css-float

I want a Text with an vertical line below it, right to this constellation i want a floating div. I dont want to set fixed widths. What i tried is this:

```
<div>
    huhu
    <hr class="green" />
    <div style="float: right">right</div>
</div>
```

what i want is the text+hr flow around the red box, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: i think your 1,3,4 image condition would be possible very easily and supportable in all browser

Comment: sorry.. this would not be ok... the line has to be interrupted

Comment: what are you saying i don't understand? are you want me to make an example for 1,3,4 images condition?

Comment: are all this condition come dynamically in code? let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible; however, the code you've given won't work without a small modification.

You need to have the right-floating div *before* the content that you want to wrap around it --
http://jsfiddle.net/S9mmU/1/

To ensure that the floated div never takes up more than half the screen, you can use the `max-width` property - `max-width:50%;`

```
<div>
    <div style="float: right; max-width:50%; border:2px solid red; padding:2em; margin:1em;">right</div>
    huhu
    <hr class="green" />
</div>
```

I've added the red border, a margin, and some padding so that you can see the effect. It should go without saying that none of these should be inline styles in practice.

Comment: i've check your fiddle but it's not true on given images condition suppose if we put more text on that side the line goes in full width? and what if the box content goes more bigger?

Comment: Hmmm... I take it that you mean how the floated div only ever takes up half of the screen in the pictures?

You should use `max-width` for that... I'll update the answer with `max-width:50%`

Comment: am asking if this `code` run in a `loop` and come with dynamic content sometime more text sometime bigger image and various conditions then your code is not solve all issue. but it's good for one condition or static `code`

Answer (score 0):

Use the border-bottom instead of

---

tag and set overflow:hidden.